# JPA CriteriaQuery calculating datetime difference for use in where predicate

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to select entities from my database that have a time difference between 2 fields less than or greater to some value. In standard SQL, this is simply accomplished using the TIMESTAMPDIFF function:

```
SELECT * from run where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, run.end_time, run.start_time) > 60;
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any equivalent in JPA 2.0.

I've tried everything I can think of, including the suggestions here: [Using TIMESTAMPDIFF with JPA criteria query and hibernate as the provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412234/using-timestampdiff-with-jpa-criteria-query-and-hibernate-as-the-provider)

```
predicate.getExpressions().add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(criteriaBuilder.function("TIMESTAMPDIFF", Long.class, criteriaBuilder.literal("SECOND"), root.get(Run_.endTime), root.get(Run_.startTime)), minSeconds))
```

simply doesn't work and since I am specifically trying to calculate large durations (60/90 days). The TIMEDIFF solution doesn't help because the max TIMEDIFF that can be returned is 35 days. Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is explanation of equivalent JPA Criteria Query of

> SELECT * from run where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, run.end_time,
>   run.start_time) > 60;

First you have to create unit expression and extend it from `BasicFunctionExpression` for which take "SECOND" parameter as a unit and override its `rendor(RenderingContext renderingContext)` method only.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilderImpl;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.RenderingContext;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.function.BasicFunctionExpression;

public class UnitExpression extends BasicFunctionExpression<String> implements Serializable {

  public UnitExpression(CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder, Class<String> javaType,
      String functionName) {
    super(criteriaBuilder, javaType, functionName);
  }

  @Override
  public String render(RenderingContext renderingContext) {
    return getFunctionName();
  }
}
```

then you use this unit expression in your JPA criteria Query.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Run> cq = cb.createQuery(Run.class);
    Root<Run> root = cq.from(Run.class);

    Expression<String> second = new UnitExpression(null, String.class, "SECOND");
    Expression<Integer> timeDiff = cb.function(
        "TIMESTAMPDIFF",
        Integer.class,
        second,
        root.<Timestamp>get(Run_.endTime),
        root.<Timestamp>get(Run_.startTime));
    List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
    conditions.add(cb.greaterThan(timeDiff, 60));
    cq.where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
    return session.createQuery(cq);
```

It is working.

Comment: Is this still possible with hibernate 6.x ? And if so how can i use it their the old import doesn't seem to work :
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.function.BasicFunctionExpression;

Answer (score 2):

```
Expression<String> month = new MyFunctionExpression(null, String.class, "MONTH");
Expression<Integer> diff = builder.function("timestampdiff", Integer.class, month, root.get(Run_.endTime), root.get(Run_.startTime));
predicates.add(builder.gt(diff, 60));
```

MyFunctionExpression extends BasicFunctionExpression and override the render method.

```
@Override
public String render(RenderingContext renderingContext) {
    return getFunctionName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that, but JPA doesn't support datediff functions. If you're using eclipselink you can use FUNC keyword, which calls native function of DB. Otherways you'll need to use native query.

Comment: JPA supports datediff functions. Read my answer.