# Criteria API order by time between two LocalDateTime

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

Given an entity with two date fields of type `LocalDateTime`:

```
class MyEntity {

    private LocalDateTime start;
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdate;

}
```

I want to write a query with criteria api that orders the result set by the time between these two dates.

```
/* ... */
Root<MyEntity> root = query.from(MyEntity.class);
Order order = ???
root.orderBy(cb.desc(order));
/* ... */
```

My ideas so far:

- `CriteriaBuilder#diff` wants its arguments to be derived from `Number`, which LocalDateTime doesn't
- `CriteriaBuilder#treat` maybe treat it as a Timestamp somehow? It is stored as timestamp in the database after all

p.s.:

- using EclipseLink 2.7.3
- looking for a solution that is not tied to a specific database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of `cb.treat(..)` that would do a downcast would not work because `Number` does not extend/inherit `LocalDateTime`. And even if it would be possible there would then be a problem because there would not be a way to cast database `timestamp` type to any `Number` either directly in database side.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32659963/6413377) which might help you. Accepted answer makes use of standard(?) SQL function `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and that should be quite implementation independent solution. You could make some generic sort based on that answer.

However, one option would also be adding a new calculated field for duration / interval like:

```
private Duration duration;

@PrePersist // update on each persist
private void calcDuration() {
    duration = Duration.between(start, lastUpdate);
}
```

Then ordering would be like:

```
Path<Long> duration = root.get("duration");  // duration is stored as bigint or like
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(duration)); // or .asc(..)
```

Naturally `duration` consumes extra space in db - and it should normally be just transient and/or calculated value - but it might also bring some performance boost.

Comment: Considering the hassle to diff the timstamps i went for the additional database field.