# How to use MySql "DATE_SUB(field, INTERVAL 08 HOUR)" in JPA Criteria

Tags: mysql, jpa, group-by, jpa-2.0, criteria

Im trying to do the following MySql code in JPA2 Criteria:

```
group by DATE(DATE_SUB(pedido0_.dataHora, INTERVAL 08 HOUR))
```

I have already managed to do the Date(field_name) part with:

```
Expression<Date> expression = criteriaBuilder.function("date", Date.class, myFiledPath);
```

But i cant find a way to do the Date_Sub part with the interval, i have tryed to do:

```
Expression<Date> expression = criteriaBuilder.function("date", Date.class, criteriaBuilder.function("date_sub", Date.class, path,criteriaBuilder.literal("INTERVAL 08 HOUR")));
```

But dosen't work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

To pass through raw tokens like `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` through to MySQL in JPA criteria queries, you can use my `OpaqueLiteralExpression` class which is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69998155/263801