# How to use MySQL's DATE_ADD with JPA Criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I need to add an interval to a date (both columns are in a table) using MySQL and JPA Criteria. I know the following functions are required:

MySQL's `DATE_ADD`:

```
DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)
```

CriteriaBuilder's `function`:

```
function(String name, Class<T> type, Expression<?>... args)
```

I also have a class to create function expressions:

```
public class SqlFunctionExpression extends BasicFunctionExpression<String> implements Serializable {

    public SqlFunctionExpression(CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder,
                                 Class<String> javaType,
                                 String functionName) {
        super(criteriaBuilder, javaType, functionName);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(RenderingContext renderingContext) {
        return getFunctionName();
    }
}
```

which can be used like `new SqlFunctionExpression(null, String.class, "MINUTE")` to create a minute unit.

However, how do I create the expression `INTERVAL expr unit` where `expr` is a table column?

Comment: You may use the next expression form instead of DATE_ADD() function: `date + INTERVAL expr unit`. For example, `SELECT table_name.datetime_column + INTERVAL 1 HOUR incremented_date FROM ...`.

Answer (score 1):

**Register function**

```
    public class CommonMySQLDialect extends MySQL57Dialect {
        public CommonMySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("date_add", new SQLFunctionTemplate(TimestampType.INSTANCE, "date_add(?1, INTERVAL ?2 ?3)"));
        }
    }
```

Add to hibernate configuration

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">yourpackage.CommonMySQLDialect</property>
```

Ready to use

```
    Expression<String> unit = new SqlFunctionExpression(null, String.class, "MINUTE");
    Expression<Integer> num = cb.literal(10);
    Expression<Date> newDate = cb.function("date_add", Date.class, cb.currentTimestamp(), num, unit);
```

Comment: code keyword  after new SQLFuenter what is it . i never seen constructor like that

Comment: Another implementation that might work and which takes two arguments: registerFunction("add_months", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "DATE_ADD(?1, INTERVAL ?2 MONTH)"));

Answer (score 1):

or we can directly do date add from java side and send that as argument for comparison like so

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(exceptionsJoinOnRoot.get(MyModelClass_.tartDate),
                    Date.from(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plus(Period.ofDays(1))
                            .toInstant()))
```

if this doesn't work we can use ADDDATE mysql function

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(exceptionsJoinOnRoot.get(MyModelClass_.tartDate),
                    criteriaBuilder.function("ADDDATE",Date.class,criteraBuilder.currentTimestamp(),criteriaBuilder.literal(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used MySQL's `ADDTIME` as a (less than ideal) workaround:

```
public static Expression<LocalDateTime> addDate(CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                                Expression<LocalDateTime> dateTime,
                                                Expression<Long> value,
                                                SqlFunctionExpression unit) {
    return cb.function("ADDTIME", LocalDateTime.class, dateTime, getValueString(cb, value, unit));
}

private static Expression<String> getValueString(CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                                 Expression<Long> value,
                                                 SqlFunctionExpression unit) {
    if (unit.equals(SqlUnits.DAY)) {
        return getDaysString(cb, value);
    } else if (unit.equals(SqlUnits.MINUTE)) {
        return getMinutesString(cb, value);
    }
    return cb.literal("");
}
private static Expression<String> getDaysString(CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                                Expression<Long> days) {
    return cb.concat(days.as(String.class), " 0:0:0");
}
private static Expression<String> getMinutesString(CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                                   Expression<Long> minutes) {
    return cb.concat(minutes.as(String.class), ":0");
}
// one method for each unit required
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass through raw tokens like `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` through to MySQL, you can use my `OpaqueLiteralExpression` class which is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69998155/263801